# AppDelegate l WalkthroughView

Tags: swift, appdelegate, walkthrough

i can add `WalkthroughView` on `UIViewController` pages but how i can add `WalkthroughView` on appDelegate?

```
 override open func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    let hasViewedWalkthrough = defaults.bool(forKey: "hasViewedWalkthrough")

    if !hasViewedWalkthrough {
       //
        print("succes")
        //
       if let pageVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "WalkthroughViewController") as? WalkthroughViewController {
           present(pageVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: it's unclear what you're trying to do. You have to explain a bit more. Don't just dump code

Comment: @Honey i need to show instruction just for one time after install the app.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you mean one of the options?

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {

        let rootViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "WalkthroughViewController")
        window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)

        window?.rootViewController = rootViewController
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

        return true
    }
}
```

Or:

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {

        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.4) {
            let viewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "WalkthroughViewController")
             window?.rootViewController?.present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: second code worked but i need to show "WalkthroughView" just for one time.

Comment: my mean is just one time after install app on device

Comment: Use bool flag in UserDefaults to check whether the screen or application was already running. Example: UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "FirstRun") after run ViewController, if UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "FirstRun") == false { } to present ViewController

Comment: i can't understand , how? please put full code as answer

Answer (score -1):

You can use the app delegate for this

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptionslaunchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool
```

Comment: I think the question was **how** to do it in the app delegate.